# How to prevent UICollectionView to overlap

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift5

I have this problem when I created too many folders into my app.

The folders overlap on other UI elements

[image: This is the normal view]

If instead, I scroll this what happened

[image]

I need to stop the scroll and not overlap the other elements

This is my code

```
 func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt _: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 10.0)
}

func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt _: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10.0
}

func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt _: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 70)
}

func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
    return arrItems.count
}
```

The Constrains

[image]

You can see my constraints to the left

Thanks In advance

Comment: issue is with your constraints ...

Comment: can you share your constrains codes? for more clear information thx

Comment: sure I have already changed a lot of times what you need to know. I'll upload the image of my constrains

Comment: @jawadAli Can you help me, because I changed the constraints 100times Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the field "Clip to Bounds" in the `UICollectionView`'s Attribute Inspector in the "View" section.

[image: UICollectionview overlap]

Comment: It is my pleasure